# Ionic HTTP request plugin/module

Tags: angular, cordova, http, ionic-framework, request

I'm quite new to Ionic and I'm facing a problem with a simple http requests in Ionic.

First of all I was trying an oAuth2 registration with `@angular/http` which failed because of CORS-reasons (something with the access-control-allow-origin header).

I succeeded using the native ionic `@ionic-native/http`-module.
Later I noticed that the native ionic module does not support PUT- or DELETE-requests (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/).

So googled again and I found the `cordova-http-plugin` (https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-HTTP), but I coundn't figure out how to use it properly.

My question now is: 
What is the best way to make an http request in Ionic/Angular?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Have a go with this ...

```
import { Http } from "@angular/http"
```

And in your constructor ...

```
public http: Http
```

And then to make the request ...

```
this.http.get('http://www.yourdomain.com/file.php).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but using `@angular/http` did't work for me... As I said above I always got an error with the access-control-allow-origin.

Comment: Do you control the API that you are trying to connect to?

Comment: No, I don't control the API.